# Boto3 get_cost_and_usage filter Getting zero cost based on tag

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cloud, boto3

I am trying to get cost consumed by each tag in AWS using Boto3 get_cost_and_usage() method.

In filter, I am passing tag key and its value but I am getting zero cost each time.

In `get_cost_and_usage()` I passed TimePeriod and Tags in the filter but I am always getting zero cost.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ce')

response = client.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': '2019-07-01',
        'End': '2019-08-01'
    },
    Metrics=['AmortizedCost'],
    Granularity='MONTHLY',
    Filter={
         "Tags": {
             "Key": "Key",
             "Values": [
                 "kubernetes.io/cluster/bmchugh-zfllx",
              ]
         }
     }
)
from pprint import pprint
pprint(response)
```

i am not getting any error but also not getting any cost getting bellow result.

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPHeaders': {'content-length': '160',
                                      'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
                                      'date': 'Fri, 23 Aug 2019 05:46:10 GMT',
                                      'x-amzn-requestid': 'f3c3d4f0-1083-4b3d-94d3-39477b4aed41'},
                      'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                      'RequestId': 'f3c3d4f0-1083-4b3d-94d3-39477b4aed41',
                      'RetryAttempts': 0},
 'ResultsByTime': [{'Estimated': False,
                    'Groups': [],
                    'TimePeriod': {'End': '2019-08-01', 'Start': '2019-07-01'},
                    'Total': {'AmortizedCost': {'Amount': '0',
                                                'Unit': 'USD'}}}]}
```

Comment: your amortized cost could be zero.

Comment: This code worked for me in my AWS account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct. When I run it with my own tags, I get the associated costs.

According to your code you have attached the following key/value pair to your resources:

> Key = kubernetes.io/cluster/bmchugh-zfllx

Make sure that the tag you specified in your code is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot vikyol  this correct answer, but i need to call many times this API. is it possible i can pass multiple tag at a time instead of calling those many tag are there those many time.

Comment: i mean key: key1,key2,key3  values[val1,val2,val3]  like this

Comment: it looks like it is not possible to specify multiple tags. only one tag key at a time but you can specify multiple values, e.g. key1=[val1,val2,val3].